# Push text following image to top of div

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have a div black bar, and a logo image that currently sits at the left as the first child element of this div. The logo image has a height larger than the black bar's fixed height of 42, so it juts out (this is a style choice)

I want to include a menu in the black bar, so I added a UL menu as the next child element.
However, it sits as the bottom of the div, outside the black bar area, because it sits inline with the logo.

I want to push the menu to the top, above the black area

[image: Div bar containing image and ul menu]

I've tried every possible combination of floats, display: inline/inline-block, margin-top, padding-top, etc. but to no avail.

Anyone got a solution?

Thanks!!!

HTML

```
<div id="black-bar">
    <a href="..." class="logo"><img src="..."></img></a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="programs.shtml">Programs & Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="recipes.shtml">Recipes</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (This is only the lat of many combos I've tried)

```
 #black-bar {
    text-align: left;
    background: #373737;
    height: 43px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 119px; 
}

#black-bar .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }


/* header menu */

#black-bar ul{
    line-height: 119px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}


#black-bar ul li{
    display: inline;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/QsnqR/)

**CSS**

```
#black-bar {
    text-align: left;
    background: #373737;
    height: 43px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 119px;
}
#black-bar .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
/* header menu */
 #black-bar ul {
    display: inline;
}
#black-bar ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#black-bar ul li a {
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is a good possible solution! Thanks. Did not think of applying it to the <a> tags

Answer (score 3):

You can take the `line-height` property from the black header.
Then you can display `li` as `inline-block` and apply padding as requited.

```
 #black-bar {
     text-align: left;
     background: #373737;
     height: 43px;
     padding-left: 60px;
     width: 100%;
     /*line-height: 119px;*/
 }
 #black-bar .logo {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 0px;
 }
 /* header menu */
 #black-bar ul  {
     display: inline;
 }
 #black-bar ul li  {
     display: inline-block;
     padding:10px 15px 0 0;
 }
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jywd3/